# Hive Error "not a SequenceFile" occuring on joining two tables in ORC "SNAPPY" format

Tags: mysql, hive, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, metastore

I got a "not a SequenceFile error" performing an outer join. It used to work under the same settings & similar tables, but now I have no idea what changed so that I am getting this error on joining rather large tables on a large key space.

I am running Hive 0.13.1 Cloudera 5.3.0, with YARN.
Both tables are STORED AS orc tblproperties ("orc.compress" = "SNAPPY").

Storage information:

```
SerDe Library:  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde
InputFormat:  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat
OutputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat
Compressed:  No
```

Diagnostic Messages for this Task:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException:
hdfs://my_cluster:9000/user/hive/warehouse/my_table/000000_0 not a
SequenceFile at
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:283)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:506)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:447)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs
(UserGroupInformation.java:1642) at
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
java.io.IOException: hdfs://my_cluster:9000/user/hive/warehouse/my_table
/000000_0 not a SequenceFile at
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.RowContainer.first
(RowContainer.java:237) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 35  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 2742.67 sec   HDFS
Read: 8762733372 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 45 minutes 42 seconds 670 msec
```

In my .hiverc

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=10000;
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=10000;
set hive.exec.max.created.files=150000;
set hive.error.on.empty.partition=true;
set hive.cli.print.header=true;
set hive.optimize.s3.query=true;
set hive.auto.convert.join=true;
set mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx2048m;
set hive.error.on.empty.partition=false;
set hive.hadoop.supports.splittable.combineinputformat=true;
set hive.enforce.bucketing=true;
set hive.optimize.bucketmapjoin=true;
set hive.mapjoin.smalltable.filesize=50000000;
set hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names=false;
set hive.cbo.enable=true;
set hive.compute.query.using.stats=true;
set hive.stats.fetch.column.stats=true;
set hive.stats.fetch.partition.stats=true;
set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled = true;
set hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled = true;
```

I experimented with declaring both tables as sequencefile, but there was a different error on a full-sized tables, but not on a small sample: IndexOutOfBound.

Metastore is MySQL.

Full list of Hive / Hadoop settings is to long to post, but I will look it up - just have no idea what to look for.

If that is something related to IO or corrupted HDFS, how do I check for HDFS health?

Comment: Is the sequence file created by MapReduceJob?

Comment: The exception is raised in a Reduce task, so that implies that one of the Mappers produced a garbage intermediate file (Reduce expects a bunch of SequenceFile). But the error message shows a file name that looks like a source file (and that one is definitely *not* a SequenceFile but an ORC file) and a Reduce has no good reason to tap into a source file directly. Quite puzzling...

Comment: Did you check the YARN logs for the Reducer **and** the 35 Mappers? Nothing weird in there?